# C function that returns two values

Tags: c, function

I have to complete the following assignment in C.

> Write a function that asks the user to enter two positive integer numbers, reads these two numbers, say a and b, and keeps asking for them until the user enters two such numbers. The function returns both numbers to the place where it was called.

I'm a little confused here. How would I ask the user to enter two values from a function? Can't you only do this from the main() function? As of now I have the following functioning code. It works fine, but of course I need this in an external function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int a(2); // initialize just as some positive number so as not to set off negative alert.
int b(2);
printf("Enter two positive numbers: \nFirst: ");
do {
    if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) { // negative alert
        printf("Woops. Those are negative. Try again. \nFirst: ");
    }
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    printf("Second: ");
    scanf(" %d", &b);
    printf("\n");
} while (a <= 0 || b <= 0);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Mixing C & C++ here, it looks like...

Comment: a function is a function. no reason you can't do this in any function you want.

Comment: Why can't you just put that code in a different function?  I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: `int a(2);` is not valid C. Did you mean C++?

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. I've been taught both C and C++ so sometimes I've been known to mix.

Comment: `int a(2)` and `int b(2)` should be `int a = 2` and `int b = 2` here.
The solution here is to simply move all that code outside into a different function. Literally just copy and paste it.

Comment: I guess my question is...does scanf work in a separate function?

Comment: what do you mean   "asks the user to enter two positive integer numbers, reads these two numbers, say a and b, and keeps asking for them until the user enters two such numbers"

Comment: @codedude Yes, of course it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I just pasted the assignment text word for word. I'm still trying to work it out. @BarathBushan

Comment: Hmm. I guess it was just a stupid assumption I made. :/ @Magtheridon96

Comment: "Can't you only do this from the main() function?" -- Are you aware that there are programs with millions of lines of C code? Do you suppose all those lines are in the `main` function? Why would there be any requirement that something can only be done from the `main` function? Where did you get such a bizarre idea? Did you even *try* to write a function to do this? I suggest reading a lot more ... books on C, articles on C, example code in C, and think and experiment a lot more before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick that no one mentioned is that another way to return multiple values from a function is to pass pointers as parameters. A common function that does this is scanf:

```
int x,y;
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
```

You can sort of view this code as the scanf returninf two values and assigning them to x and y.

Comment: hmm. interesting point

Comment: Your function declaration might be `int myfunc (int * a, int * b) {...}`.  Your call might look like `if (!myfunc (&i, &j)) {... fail ...} else {... succeed ...}`

Answer (score 2):

functions (methods in oop) in `c` and `c++` (actually in every other programing language i know) can only return one value.  use a struct  which holds both values and return it from your function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct two_ints {
    int a, b;
} two_ints_t;

two_ints_t read_two_ints();

two_ints_t read_two_ints() {
    two_ints_t two_ints;
    two_ints.a = 0;
    two_ints.b = 0;
    char tmp[32] = "";
    printf("Enter two positive numbers: \nFirst: ");
    do {
        scanf(" %s", tmp);
        two_ints.a = atoi(tmp);
        printf("Second: ");
        scanf(" %s", tmp);
        two_ints.b = atoi(tmp);
        printf("\n");
        if (two_ints.a <= 0 || two_ints.b <= 0) { // negative alert
            printf("Woops. Those are negative. Try again. \nFirst: ");
        }
    } while (two_ints.a <= 0 || two_ints.b <= 0);

    return two_ints;
}

int main() {
    two_ints_t two_ints = read_two_ints();
    printf("a=%i, b=%i\n", two_ints.a, two_ints.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing special about `main` is it is your application's entry point. You can call whatever you would like, whenever you would like<sup>1</sup>. Once the instruction pointer hits the first instruction in your entry point it is all just a stream of op-codes from there on out. Nothing special about the fact that you have "functions" besides jumping. You could inline them all too.

Foisting the code into another method only makes a difference in passing and returning information:

```
/* this signature will change if you need to pass/return information */
void work()
{
    int a = 2; /* did you really mean C++? */
    int b = 2;
    printf("Enter two positive numbers: \nFirst: ");
    do {
        if (a <= 0 || b <= 0) { /* negative alert */
            printf("Woops. Those are negative. Try again. \nFirst: ");
        }

        scanf(" %d", &a);
        printf("Second: ");
        scanf(" %d", &b);
        printf("\n");
    } while (a <= 0 || b <= 0);
}
```

Called like so:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    work(); /* assuming it is defined or declared above us */

    return 0;
}
```

<sub>1. For reasonable definitions of "whatever" and "whenever".</sub>

Comment: The assignment asks me to " return both numbers to the place where it was called." Doesn't a void function not return anything?

Comment: I'm not necessarily going to complete your assignment for you, but you're correct. Currently I am not returning anything. If you would like you can certainly alter the signature of `work` to do so. You seem to be on the right track seeing as how you realize `void` does not do what you want.

Comment: Haha, I didn't expect you to do my homework for me. :) Thanks for the help though!